# Send a combo box item into a report as a report date parameter

Tags: c#, rdlc

I want to take a date value from the database and send it into a report as a report parameter. But if I do that now I get an error (***the value provided for the report parameter is not valid for its type datetime***). I am currently using a combobox to contain the list of dates, and i want the selected item to be sent as a date parameter into the report. I am using c# and I am using the rdlc report file. Here is my code.

```
this.rptStockMismatch.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerURL"]);
    this.rptStockMismatch.ShowParameterPrompts = false;

    ReportParameter[] reportParameter = new ReportParameter[2];
    reportParameter[0] = new ReportParameter("StockCaptureDate",  this.cboStockCaptureDate.SelectedItem.ToString()); //this is where I want to insert the selected combobox itme in.
    reportParameter[1] = new ReportParameter("DepotID", this.cboDepot.SelectedValue.ToString());

this.rptStockMismatch.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameter);
this.rptStockMismatch.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: try to convert combobox value to `datetime`

Comment: @POHH I tried but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm agreeing with POHH here. The Error message says that u need a DateTime-object here.

You cast your SelectedItem into a string though. Try to search for a .ToDateTime() function if there is one and if there isn't, try to write a little function that parses your string.

```
//Assuming a Date in this fashion: DD.MM.YYYY
string[] splitDate = cboStockCaptureDate.SelectedItem.ToString()
    .Split(".".ToCharArray());

DateTime finalDate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(splitDate[2]), Int32.Parse(splitDate[1]), Int32.Parse(splitDate[0]));
```

Then add it to your ReportParameters.

Please be aware that Int32.Parse could throw some Exceptions in case the string is not a pure number.

Comment: Error: Index was outside the bounds of the Array

Comment: @Scelo This might be caused by your Date-Format looking different than the one i used. How do your Dates look? Maybe try to debug and look at the string-array and edit the constructor accordingly.

Comment: It should be cboStockCaptureDate.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() and in any case, stop the code in debug mode and look at the value of "Value" to see how it would be best to cast it.

Comment: I hear you, the text in the combobox is a list of smalldatetime values like this one : 2013-02-28 09:16:00  but displayed as 28-02-2013

Comment: @Scelo Then you just have to adjust the way the string is split so that you get your string[] with a length of 3. :)